# Execute SSIS Package Using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis

**Description Of Environment**

I have an SSIS task which executes from asp.net, the package gets data from excel files over UNC path and puts the data into a sql server databaase . I have deployed the SSIS to file system, it has windows authentication database connections and the IIS user has database access. I can log in as the AppPoolUser I have used to host the web application and open/modify the files in question so those basic permissions are there. Web App is compiled in x86.

**When it works:**

When run from Visual Studio (ctrl + shift + W) it works fine and every thing is done succefuly.

**When it doesn't work:**

When run from client browser. it upload the file but fail in the package.

**My Question**

What is different about the client and server and how do I make it work? I was under the impression that when running the web app all connections go through the AppPool User so it should behave the same on any machine server included? i need to do so without the need of CMD.

**c# Code running SSIS Package**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

public partial class Pages_Quality : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileExt =
               System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

            if (FileUpload1.FileName == "Breached.xlsx")
            {
                try
                {
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs("*:\\***\\***\\" +
                       FileUpload1.FileName);
                    Label1.Text = "Upload Done";

                    Application app = new Application();
                    Package package = app.LoadPackage(@"*:\**\**\Quality.dtsx", null);

                   DTSExecResult result = package.Execute();

                    Label2.Text = (result.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Only Breached.xls is allowed!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with Mitch this could be a security context issue. A possible way to sidestep the security context issue is to maybe create a stored procedure that executes the SSIS package instead.

Comment: How do you know it fails? From the return value? Do you have log entries? Turn and logging and get more info.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SSIS service or SSIS Component (Client Tools) installed in the machine (web server in your case) where you are deploying and running your application from?

You may have bids in the same development PC where you have Visual Studio to develop and debug your application application. Usually the SSIS component is installed along with BIDs so you do not need SSIS service to run the package. This might be the case where your package execution is fine in you development PC. However it will never work in your web server because you do not have these components installed in your web server.

Hope this will help you.

Regards,
Sandip

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel source connection, most probably the error happened because the excel driver work under 32 bit mode only, while when you try to call it from web, it's execute under 64 bit.

Check that.

Regards